# CiviEvent Live and Test Registration pages yield error when accessed

Tags: civievent, registration, online-registration

I'm currently using Wordpress 5.5; and CiviCRM version 5.25.0

I'm getting the following error log when trying to access registration pages for any of our events:

Aug 18 14:46:20  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(419): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

#1 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Contribute_Exception_InactiveContributionPageException))

#2 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1479): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

#3 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(295): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()

#4 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(343): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->render_single("", "", "civicrm")

#5 internal function: do_shortcode_tag((Array:7))

#6 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(218): preg_replace_callback("/[([?)(civicrm)(?![\w-])([^]/]*(?:/(?!])[^]/]*)*?)(?:(/)]|](?:([^...", "do_shortcode_tag", "[civicrm]")

#7 /home/example/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(203): do_shortcode("[civicrm]")

#8 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->prerender(Object(WP))

#9 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, (Array:1))

#10 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(544): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))

#11 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(758): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))

#12 /home/example/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(1285): WP->main("")

#13 /home/example/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()

#14 /home/example/public_html/index.php(17): require("/home/example/public_html/wp-blog-header.php")

#15 {main}

the resulting page provides the following generic fatal error message:

"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. The page you requested is currently unavailable."

As far as I am aware, there have not been any recent changes to our setup that would have prompted the error, as it was working fairly recently. Any tips or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on wordpress 5.5 than your CiviCRM version should be more than 5.25.x. Also can you check the shortcode that you have added in wp post/page has contribution id.

Comment: Will try upgrading and see if that works. Would you mind clarifying what you mean by checking the shortcode?

Comment: Upgrade to 5.28 worked - thanks so much!